# Class does not accept new fields after updating model.

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, entity

I am developing using VS2012, SQL Server 2008 and ASP NET MVC

I have a ADO.NET Data Model created from a SQL DB and every time I change the DB I know that I need to update the model. Using VS2012 I click in update model and I can see that the entity is updated.

the problem is that if I try to use a property from a context after update the model I still can´t use the new fields.

I am having to delete the model and recreat it again.

I am not sure I am missing something or this is the normal procedure.

Comment: Are you working in an n-tiered environment?  If so, clean and rebuild, that should update references across all of your projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you have to rebuild your solution to have the properties show up in IntelliSense.

Comment: Well, but when we run the app, VS automatically rebuild de solution. Does not it?

Comment: @GuilhermeLongo No it rebuilds what it thinks has changed. That's why there's a clean solution option. on the menu, just in case it thought wrong.